# Android WebView not loading javascript files or functions even after enabling javascript

Tags: android, webview, apk, mobile-website

I am trying to create a webview app where I want to access a website. The website works fine on chrome but when I run the webview app...it is not loading javascript files/function in the log. I get 'Uncaught error, function not defined...with the js file name mentioned in the Android Studio.

Here is my Code

```
package com.menux.sss2009;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true );
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

      //  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      //  webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
       // webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      //  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
      //  MyWebChromeClient myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
       // webView.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);

      //  WebSettings ebSettings = webView.getSettings();
    //    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     //   webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      //  webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      //  webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
      //  webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*64);

        // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
        // But it didn't work for me without this line
      //  webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
      //  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
       // webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
      //  webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

      //  webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);



       //

        final AppCompatActivity activity = this;
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different      scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    /*    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String      description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/

        webView.loadUrl("http://psh2009.net/");
       // webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.psh2009.net/",null,"text/html","UTF-8","http://www.psh2009.net/");
      //  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.psh2009.net/",null,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
    }

    /*public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }

        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }*/
}
```

I have searched stackoverflow for answer but none of them resolved my issue.
Any help is appreciated.

I have searched stackoverflow for answer but none of them resolved my issue.

This is the logcat after the login page...when the main page loads.

```
07-25 07:22:49.294 2123-2123/? I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-25 07:22:49.314 2123-2123/? I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-25 07:22:50.394 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in", source: http://117.254.84.212:3000/getjs?nadipdata=%22%7B%22url%22:%22%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Ficheck%2Ficheck.min.js%22%2C%22referer%22:%22http:%2F%2Fpsh2009.net%2F%22%2C%22host%22:%22psh2009.net%22%2C%22categories%22:%5B0%5D%2C%22reputations%22:%5B1%5D%2C%22nadipdomain%22:1%7D%22&screenheight=480&screenwidth=854&tm=1564019570223&lib=true&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0 (2)
07-25 07:23:11.444 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 3093 12436
07-25 07:23:22.234 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-25 07:23:25.624 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(195)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =", source: http://psh2009.net/js/contentloading/loadingfunctions.js (195)
07-25 07:23:25.714 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =", source: http://psh2009.net/js/contentloading/contributionscript.js (3)
07-25 07:23:25.784 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(330)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =", source: http://psh2009.net/js/contentloading/userscripts.js (330)
07-25 07:23:25.834 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =", source: http://psh2009.net/js/contentloading/loansexpenses.js (1)
07-25 07:23:26.514 2123-2123/com.menux.psh2009 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(39)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: getchartdata is not defined", source: http://psh2009.net/js/demo_dashboard.js (39)
```

The above errors are showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out the problem with the Nox Player, but I am able to have it worked in Vivo 11, and Vivo 11 Pro which has Funtouch OS 4.5 (based on Android 8.1) also the android emulator. Initially when I installed the app the webview showed the error 'net:ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED'. Then I added this line in manifest file 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"' in the 'application' tag and it worked without any issues. all the javascript files/functions are loading properly. Thanks everyone for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your url in both webview and chrome. In chrome when i load your Url in full page it was showing a **settings icon**  on scroll bar. But when i compressed chrome tab like mobile screen the **settings icon** gone. So i think its website or url issue. In android web view showing as same view and functionality like compressed chrome screen size.

Thank you

Comment: That was the default behavior for the settings icon. when on the mobile size view it automatically disappears. Thats OK. After login...the main page comes up where the number of javascript functions need to be loaded. When I click on any link that executes a javascript function, nothing happnes and when I check the log in android studio it states the error: "Uncaught error: function is not defined";

Comment: i think there is a error in java script code in the web page of the url.Need more information of logcat then only it is easy to debug

Comment: I have put up the logcat where the errors are showing up. Please check.

Comment: Earlier I was testing with Nox Player. and it is not loading javascript files properly. Then I tried the emulator with image 'Galaxy Nexus API 24 (Android 7.0 AP 24)' , on this image the website works with no issues. I dont know why the Nox player is not loading the javascript files properly.

Comment: Test in real device. You will get real feel .